# Drupal - Fatal error sessionhandler

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-8

I am receiving following errors when I try to access pages and the site becomes inaccessible(error 500).

> PHP Fatal error:  Class Drupal\Core\Database\Statement contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Drupal\Core\Database\StatementInterface::fetchObject) in /projects/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Statement.php on line 16
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class Drupal\Core\Session\SessionHandler contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read) in /projects/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php on line 15

Restarting server will solve the issue for a limited time. Just found it was a memory issue. changed the `memory_limit` to 128, 256 and 512 but really seems to have happen randomly while browsing my website

`Apache/2.4.29, PHP 7.0.26`

Answer (score 0):

Hey just need to delete cache or run drupal cron. for more details, please go to following the link.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2668564

Hope it will useful for you.

Comment: cache clearing and restarting server will solve this issue for particular time only

Comment: @sreejith, okay are you using Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Drupal 8.3.7 Apache/2.4.29, PHP 7.0.26